# showing subset of total as stacked bar using geom_col (world bank data)

Tags: ggplot2

I'm working with some World Bank data. I'm trying to use geom_col (or possibly geom_bar) to summarize the contribution of different loan types to total investment by project name.

```
## this is my data

filtered_long <- structure(list(Project.name = c("Nkhotakota solar plant", "Kuvaninga Energia power plant", 
"Ressano Garcia Gas-Fired Plant", "Central Termica de Ressano Garcia", 
"Mocuba Solar PV Plant", "Central Solar Metoro", "Symbion Dodoma Power Plant", 
"Symbion Rental Ubungo Power Plant", "PowerGen Tanzania Mini-Grids Portfolio", 
"Sinohydro Kafue Gorge Lower HPP", "TATA Itezhi-Tezhi HPP", "Itezhi-Tezhi Power Corporation Transmission line", 
"Maamba Coal-Fired Power Plant- Phase-I", "Bangweulu Solar PV Plant", 
"Ngonye Solar PV Plant", "Nkhotakota solar plant", "Kuvaninga Energia power plant", 
"Ressano Garcia Gas-Fired Plant", "Central Termica de Ressano Garcia", 
"Mocuba Solar PV Plant", "Central Solar Metoro", "Symbion Dodoma Power Plant", 
"Symbion Rental Ubungo Power Plant", "PowerGen Tanzania Mini-Grids Portfolio", 
"Sinohydro Kafue Gorge Lower HPP", "TATA Itezhi-Tezhi HPP", "Itezhi-Tezhi Power Corporation Transmission line", 
"Maamba Coal-Fired Power Plant- Phase-I", "Bangweulu Solar PV Plant", 
"Ngonye Solar PV Plant", "Nkhotakota solar plant", "Kuvaninga Energia power plant", 
"Ressano Garcia Gas-Fired Plant", "Central Termica de Ressano Garcia", 
"Mocuba Solar PV Plant", "Central Solar Metoro", "Symbion Dodoma Power Plant", 
"Symbion Rental Ubungo Power Plant", "PowerGen Tanzania Mini-Grids Portfolio", 
"Sinohydro Kafue Gorge Lower HPP", "TATA Itezhi-Tezhi HPP", "Itezhi-Tezhi Power Corporation Transmission line", 
"Maamba Coal-Fired Power Plant- Phase-I", "Bangweulu Solar PV Plant", 
"Ngonye Solar PV Plant", "Nkhotakota solar plant", "Kuvaninga Energia power plant", 
"Ressano Garcia Gas-Fired Plant", "Central Termica de Ressano Garcia", 
"Mocuba Solar PV Plant", "Central Solar Metoro", "Symbion Dodoma Power Plant", 
"Symbion Rental Ubungo Power Plant", "PowerGen Tanzania Mini-Grids Portfolio", 
"Sinohydro Kafue Gorge Lower HPP", "TATA Itezhi-Tezhi HPP", "Itezhi-Tezhi Power Corporation Transmission line", 
"Maamba Coal-Fired Power Plant- Phase-I", "Bangweulu Solar PV Plant", 
"Ngonye Solar PV Plant"), TotalInvestment = c(67, 98.67, 200, 
273, 84, 56, 4.7, 129.4, 8.5, 1500, 239, 110, 830, 59, 45, 67, 
98.67, 200, 273, 84, 56, 4.7, 129.4, 8.5, 1500, 239, 110, 830, 
59, 45, 67, 98.67, 200, 273, 84, 56, 4.7, 129.4, 8.5, 1500, 239, 
110, 830, 59, 45, 67, 98.67, 200, 273, 84, 56, 4.7, 129.4, 8.5, 
1500, 239, 110, 830, 59, 45), Donor = c("ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", 
"ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", 
"ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", "ifc_loan", 
"ifc_loan", "miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", 
"miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", 
"miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", 
"miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", "miga_guarantee", 
"ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", 
"ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", 
"ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", 
"ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", "ida_guarantee", "other_loan", 
"other_loan", "other_loan", "other_loan", "other_loan", "other_loan", 
"other_loan", "other_loan", "other_loan", "other_loan", "other_loan", 
"other_loan", "other_loan", "other_loan", "other_loan"), Amount = c(0, 
0, 0, 99, 45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 57, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 21, 42, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 70, 0, 0, 12
)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), class = "data.frame")
```

**What I'd like to do:** I'm trying to generate a bar plot of total investment by project name, and then where relevant, showing amounts (shown in Amount column) contributed by different donors e.g. IFC, MIGA etc (in the donor column).

This is what I have so far:

```
plot <- ggplot(filtered_long, aes(x = Project.name, y = TotalInvestment, fill = Amount)) +
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()+
  theme_bw()
```

However the plot is translating the Amount column as a scaled value with increasing amounts starting from zero. (see figure below) 
[image: Resulting Plot]

But I just need to summarize the amount relative to the total. And also show where the loan amount is from i.e., linking to the donor column.

Any idea how to do this? **NOTE** I had to convert my data into long format so you will see some repetition in project names, and also for some projects there was no donor/loan.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is your desired output? Should each bar be stacked to 100%?

Comment: Hi Ryan. No stacking needed as I'm interested in full investment for each project.

Comment: @RyanJohn, meant to tag you. Kindly let me know if you can help!

Comment: I guess I don't understand what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some form of "Unknown giver" to fill the space between the total loan amount (repeated) and the specific donors known.

[Plot I think you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYhTQ.png)

```
# need to make other categ
# gather all the amounts from known donors
test <- filtered_long %>%
    group_by(Project.name)%>%
    summarise(Amount_known_donors = sum(Amount))

# lets get those totals from 
total_donations <- filtered_long %>%
    select(Project.name, TotalInvestment)%>%
    distinct(Project.name, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    left_join(test) %>%
    mutate(
        Amount = TotalInvestment - Amount_known_donors,
        Donor = "Unknown_Source"

    )%>%
    select(-TotalInvestment, -Amount_known_donors)%>%
    full_join(filtered_long)


plot <- ggplot(total_donations, aes(x = Project.name, y = Amount, fill = `Donor`)) +
    geom_col()+
    coord_flip()+
    theme_bw()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This code works and is exactly what I need.

Comment: @Lulu if you want to make the project value differences obvious, I would edit the plot code to show decreasing order of projects by project value. Doing this necessitates adding labels, though.
`ggplot(total_donations, aes(x = reorder(Project.name, Amount), y = Amount, fill = `Donor`)) +
geom_col() +
coord_flip() +
labs(title = "Amount per Project", x = "Amount", y = "Project")`

Comment: Thank you, this looks better. Also any ideas on faceting by country with facet grid? the total_donations dataframe has NA values now for some countries (i.e. from the earlier join). You know how to maintain the countries? @mj_whales

Comment: Does editing the test data with `group_by(Project.name, country)` and then adding `facet_grid(~country)` after `geom_col()` in the plot help? @Lulu